# Find rows with the same values in a column

Tags: sql, oracle, select, nested

I've a table LESSON like this

```
| Student_id | Lesson_id |
| ---------- |- -------- |
| 352-03-3624|  10359427 |
| 352-03-3624|  10359449 |
| 805-17-4144|  58149917 |
| 805-17-4144|  58149968 |
```

I have to look for students who have taken the same lessons, ie who have the same lesson_id.

I used this query:

```
select * from lesson e
where exists
(select null from lesson i
 where e.lesson_id = i.lesson_if and e.student_id <> i.student_id)
 order by lesson_id
```

but it doesn't work very well.

Is there someone who can help me?

thanks

I'm finding for every studend if there is another student who follows the same lessons.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work very well"? This looks fine. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/439b68/1 Can you provide sample data such that it doesn't work? Gnqz answer is valid if a student cannot take the same lesson multiple times, but not otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `HAVING` clause:

```
WITH lessons AS
(
  SELECT '352-03-3624' as student_id, '10359427' as lesson_id FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT '352-03-3624', '10359449' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT '805-17-4144', '58149917' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT '805-17-4144', '58149968' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT '805-17-4144', '10359427' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT '805-17-4143', '10359427' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT '805-17-4144', '10359449' FROM dual 
)
SELECT lsns.lesson_id, lsns.student_id
  FROM lessons lsns
     , (SELECT COUNT(1), lesson_id
          FROM lessons
         GROUP BY lesson_id
        HAVING COUNT(1) > 1) lsns_cnt
 WHERE lsns_cnt.lesson_id = lsns.lesson_id;
```

PS. I added more data in order to have a result set. It contains the course and the student that are matching the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be to use `count` in its analytic form and then fetch rows whose *count* is larger than 1 (which means that there are two or more students who took the same lesson).

Sample data:

```
SQL> WITH lessons (student_id, lesson_id) AS
  2  (
  3    SELECT '352-03-3624', '10359427' FROM dual UNION ALL
  4    SELECT '352-03-3624', '10359449' FROM dual UNION ALL
  5    SELECT '805-17-4144', '58149917' FROM dual UNION ALL
  6    SELECT '805-17-4144', '58149968' FROM dual UNION ALL
  7    SELECT '805-17-4144', '10359427' FROM dual UNION ALL
  8    SELECT '805-17-4143', '10359427' FROM dual UNION ALL
  9    SELECT '805-17-4144', '10359449' FROM dual
 10  )
```

Query begins here:

```
 11  select lesson_id, student_id
 12  from (select lesson_id,
 13               student_id,
 14               count(*) over (partition by lesson_id) cnt
 15        from lessons
 16       )
 17  where cnt > 1
 18  order by lesson_id, student_id;

LESSON_I STUDENT_ID
-------- -----------
10359427 352-03-3624
10359427 805-17-4143
10359427 805-17-4144
10359449 352-03-3624
10359449 805-17-4144

SQL>
```